# Removal of Index Types in ElasticSearch 7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

Can someone elaborate on the reason why types are deprecated while creating index in elastic search version 7.

I went through the doc link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html mentioned by elastic search but still not able to get why is it.

I think types were helpful in searching faster through documents as similar documents are grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

what you are suggesting there, "searching faster through documents as similar documents are grouped together", is no different from using a field called `filter_field` and using that (which that link talks about)

however, types as they were implemented, were a bit more than just a data filtering field. and the implementation approach caused a number of issues with the way that users interacted with Elasticsearch, and the flexibility of Elasticsearch as it scales

[this section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html#_why_are_mapping_types_being_removed) goes into those technical details, and if that's not clear then it'd be great to understand why as we can make changes to it :)

Comment: The example that they have mentioned wherein user_name field is present in both user and tweet type points that if user_name is given different data type such as text or keyword, then when deleting that field can lead to ambiguity. Is the understanding correct ?

Comment: yep. it meant the `user_name` could be mapped as an `integer` under the `user` type and also a `keyword` under the `tweet` type. with both fields being in the same index! which is not ideal at all